# Pig UDF (to load data from api)

Tags: apache-pig

I am trying to write my own UDF to load the data from the endpoints. Below is the scenario

```
// A = load the user information from the cassandra db 
// B = iterate through the data and make string of userids (1,2,3) 
// C = send it to    some UDF which can go to some external api to fetch the user  information 
// D = join A and C on user id 
// E = group by information fetched from UDF 
// dump E;
```

As far as I understood there are only 4 types of UDF. Load, Filter, EvalFunc and Store. I tried LoadFunc but looks like it always needs some filename location to load the information from. I don't want to read from file.

Is there any way to achieve the above scenario.

Comment: You should use evalfunc that takes in a tuple (fields). Your UDF can call REST or Web service using one or many fields in that input tuple and build an output tuple.

Comment: Which alias are you trying to find a solution for - A or C?